# Xpath to select only direct siblings with matching attributes

Tags: python, xpath

I have the following example document:

```
<root>
  <p class="b">A</p>
  <p class="b">B</p>
  <p class="a">C</p>
  <p class="a">D</p>
  <p class="b">E</p>
  <x>
    <p class="b">F</p>
  </x>
</root>
```

I am looking for an xpath expression which selects all *direct* siblings of a given node with matching class attributes, not any sibling.  In above example, the first two `<p class="b">` A-B should be selected; likewise the two `<p class="a">` C-D, likewise the fifth single `<p class="b">` E as it has no *direct* siblings; likewise the single `<p class="b">` F inside of `<x>`. Note that in this context B and C are not direct siblings because they have different class attribute valued!

What I have is this:

```
xml.xpath("//p") # This selects all six <p> elements.
xml.xpath("//p[@class='b']") # This selects all four <p class="b"> elements.
xml.xpath("//p/following-sibling::p[@class='b']") # This selects all <p class="b"> sibling elements, even though not direct siblings.
```

The last expression selects the fifth sibling as well, although there are non-matching siblings inbetween.

How do I select only direct siblings with the same `class` value?

**Edit** To clarify: note how the last two are individual selections, not siblings!

**Edit** I have saved an example [here](http://www.xpathtester.com/obj/d091aa13-df0b-455d-be9d-66a7ce66c477).  The Xpath expression based on `/root/p[1]` is supposed to select `A, B, C, D`.

Answer (score 20):

To get the very next sibling, you can add the position - 1 meaning right beside.

```
following-sibling::*[1]
```

To ensure that the next sibling is of a specific node type, you can add the following filter, where p is the node type we want to match.

```
[self::p]
```

If you only want ones with the same attribute, you would also need to specify the attribute on the first p element.

So if you just want class b p elements that are immediately after a class b p element, you can do the following. This would just give you the second p element.

```
//p[@class='b']/following-sibling::*[1][@class='b'][self:p]
```

It sounds like you might actually want any class b element which is adjacent to another class b element. In that case, you can check the following and preceding sibling. The following would give you the first 2 p elements.

```
//p[@class='b'][following-sibling::*[1][@class='b'][self::p] 
                or preceding-sibling::*[1][@class='b'][self::p]]
```

Comment: Almost there, yes :)  Now can I extend the immediate following/preceeding to *any* number, i.e. any directly immediate sibling of `<p class="b">` ?

Comment: Can you give an example? Do you mean if there are three in a row then all three should get selected? This should already  do that.

Comment: Yes, if there were N `<par class='b'>` elements in a row, I'd want to select all N of them. However, they all need to be `<par>` nor just any of `class="b"`. I just added a link to an example where you can play around, see the 2nd edit of the question above.

Comment: I updated the answer to check that the adjacent sibling is of the specific type. For example `<p class="b"></p><x class="b"></x>` will not return anything (since the second class b is not of the same type). However, I am not sure why your new example would only return A/B/C/D. G/H/I and K/L are also groups of adjacent p elements with class b (just different groups). Are you also saying you only want the first group?

Comment: Correct, that's what I mean with *direct* siblings, what you refer to as a group :-)  D and G are not direct siblings because there are other siblings (the two `<p class="a">` elements) separating the two, i.e. they are of different groups.

Comment: I agree that D and G are not direct siblings. But G and H are also direct siblings that match the criteria. I do not know off the top of my head how you would get the one group but not the other. I will have to think about it.

Comment: Oh...  oh I see what you're saying!  The Xpath expression would select *all* groups into one selection?  Didn't think of that.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
//p[@class='b']/following-sibling::p[following-sibling::p[@class='a'] and @class='b']
```

It returns all following siblings that are `@class='b'` and them self have following siblings with `@class='a'`. Though it would not work for last `<p>` as it does not have following siblings.